How connect DuckDB as a data source for BIRT
I tried the instructions posted on the Duckdb web site about JDBC connections but have no been able to get it to work. Here is what I have done:

Downloaded the duckdb_jdbc-1.0.0-javadoc.jar java file
Added driver to BIRT using the Managed JDBC driver screen

Here is the error message and the connection settings screen.

Full text of the error message below.
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Failed to create a connection. Please verify the connection properties.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.profile.JDBCSelectionPageHelper$TestInProcessDialog$TestConnectionJob$1.run(JDBCSelectionPageHelper.java:191)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:132)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4058)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3676)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:608)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.profile.JDBCSelectionPageHelper$8.widgetSelected(JDBCSelectionPageHelper.java:908)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:265)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:91)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4285)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1160)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4083)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3673)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.actions.NewDataSourceAction.run(NewDataSourceAction.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:581)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:415)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:91)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4285)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1160)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4083)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3673)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1042)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:152)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:639)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:546)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:173)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:208)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:143)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:439)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:271)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:668)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:605)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1481)

The Duckdb database file is not password protected. Thanks in advance.

duckdb_jdbc-1.0.0-javadoc.jar might not be correct jar, it's usually where the source code is. Try https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/duckdb/duckdb_jdbc/1.0.0/duckdb_jdbc-1.0.0.jar or whatever the version you're using
